# Finding objects that retain an particular object

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, instruments

How can I find object(s) that holds an object in heap? In Instruments (Allocations) I can see whole history of reference count record for particular object. But record has like 200 entries and it's really not trivial for me to orientate in it and find what object causes that reference count is 1 when I'm expecting it to be 0 (deallocated).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's technically possible since there is no relation attribute between 'owner' and retained object